# How to import pygame in visual studio code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pygame

I use visual studio code for coding (python) and now I have to write a program with pygame for my project and I can't `import pygame` in visual studio code (I can `import` it with the python script, it just can't be `import`ed in visual studio code).

Comment: in console of vscode use this command: pip install pygame

Comment: To elaborate on @Mehrdad's suggestion: There's a section on installing `matplotlib` in the [Install and use packages](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_install-and-use-packages) section of the [Visual Studio Code Get Started Tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial). Something similar should work for `pygame`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution I tried:

From left bottom of your vs code you can find python environment, you can in the image I marked red:

[image]

after clicking in the red marked area you can see below option to select:

[image]

from the option select your desired one. Suppose first i was try selecting 2nd one but it was not working then i tried with the last one and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open the terminal of Vscode.
2. Type `pip install pygame` or `pip3 install pygame`.
3. Import pygame and enjoy it.

Answer (score 2):

If it works in the console when you type 'python yourscript.py' but not in vs code, you should press ctrl+shift+p and use clic on Python select interpreter to switch to the right env. if it sstill doesn't work then install the package by running 'python -m pip install pygame'

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is the you could be using VS code in restricted mode.
make sure you're in a trusted browser on the app

Answer (score 0):

I have just typed this in VS Code and pygame is installed:

```
pip3 install pygame
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Valid and working pygame installation (at the time of posting), using Conda environments and **python 3.10**:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pygame
```

Using pip as others have suggested should work (in most cases), but if your aim is to have robust dependencies conda is probably a bit better.

Don't forget to select the interpreter in vs code, it'll throw errors or simply won't show up if using pygame packages from other channels, such as [this one](https://anaconda.org/CogSci/pygame)