# Module Not Found, but Requirement already satisfied

Tags: python, pygame

In my code I have:

'''import pygame'''

When I run:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'**

When I pip install pygame (also tried pip3 install pygame and pip3.7 install pygame):

**Requirement already satisfied: pygame in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.0.1)**

Really lost here any help appreciated.

python --version = Python 3.7.4

pip --version =

pip 21.2.4 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

Comment: What command are you using to run your script? Use `python -m pip install pygame` to ensure you run pip for the same python install as the `python` command

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: pygame in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.0.0.dev6)

Okay so doing this it says pygame is in anaconda, but if you look above it says it is just in my python3.7 lib?

Comment: And what command is being used to run the script?

Comment: So it worked when I open my terminal and cd into the file and do python filename.py but when I am in VSCode and click "Run Python File in terminal" it gives this error.

Comment: VSCode may be using a different python installation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62922929/2280890) for instructions on how to configure VSCode correctly.

Comment: ^ This worked. Thanks I had to change my python from 3.7.6 to 3.7.3 in VS code...

Answer (score 1):

While getting such error even after installing the required module, check for the following:

The python environment/ installation used by your IDE should be same as the environment where the module is installed.

Else, change the environment to the Python environment
 `paste the path to python.exe inside bin folder of your environment`

And install the package again.

**Specific for VS Code**
Click on `python followed by version number or venv`in the bottom ribbon of the editor and add the path to interpreter or choose an existing interpreter you want to use.